# 3 conditions with nested if and AND function in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Iam simply trying categories some values, if satisfies some conditions.

[image: this is my need]

if a student get mark according to the plan , I need to show correspond plan.

like this,

if the student satisfies plan 1 condition,
Result want to be Plan1

if the student satisfies plan 2 condition,
[image]

if the student didn't meet above 2 conditions, then show "NO PLAN"

I used this formula,

```
=IF(AND(H86>=200,Q86>=250,Y86>=14,AD86>=17,AI86>=18,AN86>=18),"Plan 1",IF(OR(H86>=180,H86<200,Q86>=225,Q86<250,Y86>=13,Y86<14,AD86>=15,AD86<17,AI86>=16,AI86<18,AN86>=16,AN86<18),"Plan 2","NO Plan"))
```

In this formula, the 2nd if contains 2 conditions, if the mark is between plan 1 and plan 2 we need show Plan 2 also if mark is greater than and equal to plan 2 , we need to show Plan2. here iam stuck.

Comment: In the second `IF`, just remove the test that grade is less than plan 1 requirements.

Comment: it worked. thanks . please tell me the logic.

Comment: An `IF` has three parts: `condition`, `result-when-true`, `result-when-false`. If the condition is true then the `result-when-true` part is evaluated. If `condition` is false, the `result-when-false` is evaluated. In either case, the alternative is ignored. In your case, if the outer `IF` is true then the result will be "Plan 1". The else part is ignored. If the inner `IF` is executed it means that the outer `IF` *had* to be false. So you know that at least one of the conditions was not met.

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation. :) :)